Can an idea be patented after the idea has been published?
The question is as simple as stated. I have an idea. I want the idea to be known. I do not have the resources to protect myself, and that is just fine. But can someone else claim a patent after I have published this? It's a bit of an honour thing for me. It's ok I can not pursue this, but I would not appreciate someone else claiming it is their idea whether in reality it is not.

It should not be possible for anyone
to get a patent on an invention whose description you have published. In a very few places, notably the U.S., there is a sort-of grace period that would allow you to change your mind if you filed within a year.
However it depends on the patent examiner finding your publication when they do their search. Patent searchers primarily search patent publications. That is granted patents and published patent applications on a world-wide basis.
If nothing turns up they will look in other literature but they may not find your disclosure where you published it.
The second issue is the sufficiency of your description. An “idea” without adequate description of at least one way to achieve its realization is not an invention, just an idea.
It may be that your invention has already been thought of before. You could search patent literature yourself to try to find it.

Once an invention is publicly known, it shouldn’t be patentable. The publication represents “prior art”. A couple of provisos however. The publication needs to be discoverable by the patent examiner or else a patent might get improperly granted. A patent can be challenged after granting but that can be messy and expensive. Also patent applications don’t generally get published until 18 months after filing so it is possible someone else has already filed before your publication.
